# Wifi Adapter not listing any wifi networks

Tags: wireless-networking

I am a beginner in ethical hacking. I bought a qualcomm atheros ar9271 wifi adapter. When I connected it in Windows 10, it shows the below list of wifi networks.

[image]

But when I go to the kali linux VM (VirtualBox), and put the adapter to monitor mode, I got no wifi networks:

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

please help

[kali wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7CAo.png)

[image]

Comment: This isn't a security question but a network config question. How are you running Kali? On a different computer? In a VM? dual-booting? Is wifi connected to anything via the normal wifi connection UI?

Comment: in virtual box. normal wifi connection ui already provided in as first image in windows. you want kali linux?

Comment: yes, I want info from the situation that is a problem.

Comment: How did you set up the networking in VirtualBox?

Comment: okay. I didn't do anything. it's already working means I can browse the web.

Comment: and have you checked the documentation for the command to do some troubleshooting? https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng

Comment: no I didn't. I have given the image above kali wifi. but that's not showing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7CAo.png

Comment: So, just to make sure, this is a USB adapter, right? Did you _really_ make sure it works for normal operation, first on the host (Windows) then inside the VM? Please provide the output of `iw dev` on Linux. If at all possible, do not use screenshots for text. Paste the text in a code block instead.

Comment: yes a usb adapter. iw dev lists 2 types. interface wlan0, wlanmon

Answer (score 1):

I use WiFi in a Kali Virtual Machine (VMware in my case).

The connection you get in a plain Virtual Machine (Virtual Box, VMware) is the host internet connection.  It looks like Ethernet.

If you wish to use WiFi in the Virtual Machine, you do this with a USB Wireless Connection and then connect this to the VM with USB Pass Through.

This works fine.

You will need to disconnect the Host Network Connection for the Virtual Machine in Virtual Box Guest Settings.

See:   [VBOX network settings](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/)

Try USB Pass Through with the Adapter you purchased. You may need the Linux driver for it.

I use a Panda PUA08 for the USB Wireless and that also works fine.

Comment: i didn't get it. how to disconnect the host network connection?

Comment: Look here:   https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/   ...  You can uncheck "Enable the network adapter"   You only want to disconnect this so that you can connect the USB Wireless you passed through